# Prevent TextView overlapping another in ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I'm encountering an issue where the `"Den Dolder"` TextView is always overlapping the date TextView. I have tried using `app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/date_txtView"` but it has no effect surprisingly!

That's okay:

[image: That's okay]

That's not okay:

[image: That's not okay]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short solution:**

Try to add `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"` and `android:layout_width="0dp"` to both of your textViews - they will both take the same width in the layout.

**Another solution for more complicated layouts:**

You need to tell both of your text views to be in a width of `0dp`, so they will drop a line if the text is too long.

**For example**, set a [Chain](https://medium.com/@nomanr/constraintlayout-chains-4f3b58ea15bb) between your  2 textViews like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView4"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**And it will look like this** (no textView overlaps another one, they just drop down a line):

[image]